# Git failed with fatal error

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Syncing code from a branch gives me this error message in Visual Studio 2017. This used to work a couple of days ago and no changes has been made. How can I solve this?

[image]

Comment: If you do the same from the command line do you get a more useful error message? PS. There was a Azure issue with authentication yesterday: if you are using git hosted in TFS this could be the problem. Re-try after restarting VS.

Comment: Hi @Richard doing a Pull from the command line, I get authentication failed even if the credentials are correct. I tried logging in to the url where the code is hosted in on our git server, and it worked from the web-browser. Having norwegian charcters like, 'æ', 'ø' and 'å' in the password might cause some issues?

Comment: Alright. So basically, have norwegian characters in the password denied me from logging into our git server. Once I changed the password, doing a git pull I got the message saying that I needed to commit a file - the strange thing was that this file didnt show up in Visual Studio until I did a git pull from command line..

Comment: No idea where such character set issues could cause problems (but there are plenty). I've found that VS's git integration tries to be helpful, `git status` etc. on the command line avoid that helpfulness: not all help is useful (eg. I don't think VS shows changes to files not in the project).